# A comment got removed but the flag is marked as declined: a bug?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, comment-flags, deleted-comments

I've flagged a couple of comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing/19814255#19814255) (they were basically "thanks" comments as far as I remember). There are no comments now indeed, but one of the flags [is shown as declined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3995261). Is this a bug or something else?

Comment: Your flags page wont be visisble for other users. Also its not a _bug_. A moderator likely declined it. Only a mod can clarify

Comment: Which kind of flags did you cast? What was the concrete content of those comments?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to call bug on this one.  It says that you are the deletion user, which must mean you got a binding vote because of the "thanks" in the comment, but the flag was marked as declined anyway.

Comment: The system-deleted one wasn't declined. It was marked helpful. The other flag was declined and then deleted. Likely a misclick on the mod's part... it happens from time to time. It's not going to count against you or anything.